# mysql database cannot connect with cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting, cpanel

i have mysql database over cpanel, i want to access through my localhost page..

```
<?php
$con1 = mysql_connect("mywebsiteip","mysql_username","mysql_user_password");
if(!$con1)
{
    die ("Could not connect " . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo "Good connection";
}
mysql_close($con1);
?>
```

When i run it, it cannot connect to mysql database over cpanel. and i even tried up

```
$con1 = mysql_connect("mywebsiteip:portnumber","mysql_username","mysql_user_password");
```

Can any let me know, which one is good way. Below is the image or error
[image]

Comment: What is the error message returned by `mysql_error()`?

Comment: Tried with passing "localhost" in place of website IP ?

Comment: @Alfred Yes!, i tried with localhost, its not working.. If i use localhost then it will take users localhost database system

Comment: @Bjoern     Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

    Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is kn (trying to connect via tcp://mywebsiteip:myportnumber)

    Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

    Could not connect php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known and it only in the connection string line 2 error

Comment: In that case, don't localhost, but a proper ip address where your mysql server is accessable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the correct connection code!

```
$con1 = mysql_connect("localhost:/tmp/mysql.sock","mysql_username","mysql_user_password");
```

I hope this should / must work for you. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

By default, cPanel-installed mysql databases only allow connections from the localhost (ie the server cpanel/mysql is installed on). To add other hosts, log in to cPanel and go to 'Remote Database Access Hosts' (this may be called something slightly different depending on version).

You can add your IP address, hostname or `%` to allow connections from any computer. However, specifying `%` is a big security risk, so use it with caution.

FYI, this question really belongs on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com), as it involves administration more than programming.

Comment: if i add my ipaddress in there, can i able to access from other computers over internet.

Answer (score 1):

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: 
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known
```

This error messages suggests that `localhost` can't be resolved, therefore the "client" (your php script) doesn't know where to send the connect request to.

Either check your DNS settings or use an IP adress instead, where your MySQL server is accessible.

Comment: where can we get the ip address of mysql server, is it same as cpanel Shared IP Address

Comment: usually your webspace provider gives you those details.

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to connect remote ip

1. Mysql server need to accept remote connection
2. Mysql user need to have remote access previlage

if you dont have 1 of them it wont work.